# Duplicate MethodID in query

Tags: php, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a query that is using a subquery, and I can't seem to figure out why it is telling me I have duplicate methodID's. The query is supposed to take the data and order by and group by for showing only the latest single result for a given studentID where there could be multiple results with different timestamps but same studentID

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT *
            , o.methodName oldName
            , n.methodName newName
            , s.firstName fName
            , s.lastName lName 
         FROM changeReport r
         LEFT 
         JOIN methodLookup o
           ON o.methodID = r.oldMethod
         LEFT 
         JOIN methodLookup n
           ON n.methodID = r.newMethod
         JOIN students s
           ON s.studentID = r.studentID
         LEFT 
         JOIN staffaccounts a
           ON r.staffID = a.staffID
        WHERE 31 IN (newSubMethod,oldSubMethod) 
          AND date(timestamp) = CURRENT_DATE
     ) a
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT students.studentID
            , MAX(timestamp) timestamp
         FROM changeReport r
         LEFT 
         JOIN methodLookup o
           ON o.methodID = r.oldMethod
         LEFT 
         JOIN methodLookup n
           ON n.methodID = r.newMethod
         JOIN students s
           ON s.studentID = r.studentID
         LEFT 
         JOIN staffaccounts a
           ON r.staffID = a.staffID
        WHERE 31 IN (newSubMethod,oldSubMethod) 
          AND date(timestamp) = CURRENT_DATE
    ) b
   ON b.studentID = a.studentID
  AND b.timestamp = a.timestamp;
```

Any ideas on how this could  be?

Comment: Both `o` and `n` has a `methodID` field, an in 3rd line you `SELECT` *... Should try something like `SELECT r.*`, or another alias you need...

Comment: Usually best to avoid using `SELECT *` where you can. It creates issues like these.

Comment: Would you mind giving me an example? I'm having a hard time following.